# Two forces and their equivalent single force

Tags: vectors

Two forces $i + j$ and $2i + 2j$ act at points whose position vectors are $i + 2j$ and $i + j$, respectively. Show that they are equivalent to a single force and find the vector equation of the line of action.

**What I have tried?**

I tried to solve the two vector equations, but they are parallel and naturally do not meet. So next I tried to sketch it out to see if something would click but that did not help.

I am supposed to solve this without using the principle of moments.

Comment: The forces are parallel, but only if they act on a body with CM at a point where they produce no net torque.  You are expected to find the line where the CM must be for the torque to be zero.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent force is given by the sum of forces $\sum \vec F = 3 \hat{i} + 3\hat{j} = F_{total}$. This force must exert the same moment about the origin (or at any point in the plane),

$$ \sum M_0 = \vec r_1 \times F_1 + \vec r_2 \times F_2 = \vec r_{f} \times F_{total}$$
where $ \vec r_1 = \hat i + 2 \hat j, \vec r_2 = \hat i + \hat j, F_1 = \hat i + \hat j$, and $F_2 = 2\hat i + 2\hat j$. Also, $ \times$ represents the vector cross product.

To solve for the line, set $\vec r_f = [x, y]^T$.

Comment: What does the r mean?

Comment: I have made changes to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

When acceleration ( Force per unit mass ) is integrated we need velocity and displacement as speed and position vector boundary values to find ensuing motion. They can be prescribed independently and arbitrarily in any given situation as also done here.

By individual parallelograms of resultant forces, velocities and positions are determined.

Resultant force is
$$ (i+j)+(2 i+2 j)= (3 i +3j) \text{ acting at 45 deg to x-axis}.  $$

[image]

In the present simple case the forces are collinear so the resultant red force DG also acts along the same line, arrow start position point shifted to the resultant position vector tip at  $(2,3),$ drawn to scale as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

The resulting force vector is given by the sum of the vectors of the two forces, namely:

$(i+j)+(2i+2j)=3i+3j$.

The application point is:

$i+\frac{4}{3}j$.

Consider the components of the forces along the x-axis:

$F_{1x}=1$, $F_{2x}=2$, $F_{x}=3$;

indicating with $d$ the distance between $F_{1x}$ and $F_{2x}$, which is equal to $d=1$, we can write that:

$d_{1}$ is the distance between $F_{1x}$ and $F_{x}$

while

$d_{2}$ is the distance between $F_{2x}$ and $F_{x}$.

We can assert this because the resulting $F_{x}$ lies between $F{1x}$ and $F_{2x}$, as the forces are parallel and of the same direction. We can then write that the area underlying $F_{1x}$ and $d_1$ must be equivalent to the area of the rectangle of sides $F_{2x}$ and $d_{2}$:

$F_{1x}d_{1}=F_{2x}d_{2}$.

By substituting their own values for the vaiable, we obtain:

$d_{1}=2d_{2}$,

$d-d_{2}=2d_{2}=1- d_{2}=2d_{2}$,

$d_{2}=\frac{1}{3}$.

We conclude by saying that the point of application of the resulting force is:

$i+\frac{4}{3}j$,
and that the resulting force is worth: $3i+3j$.